# WPF Contextmenu load Items based on caller element

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a Canvas with a lot (1000+) elements on it.
If I open the Contextmenu on one particular element, I want to do a database request and display the resultset as Menuitems. In my case the resultset are the commands for this element (based on user and type).

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Sure I can cache the complete information for each element and bind to a "SelectedElementCommands" Collection. But that's not a good option.

Can I eventually trigger a ObjectDataProvider on ContextMenu.Open?

Best regards

Comment: Why not create a command object which creates the menuitems list. And bind that command to every element in xaml?

Comment: And how do I trigger this command?

Comment: It is a command. You can bind it to your element's mousedown or similar property. In CanExecute, check if it is right click and if the contextmenu is to be loaded.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!

Comment: So, did you get it to work? If yes, you can post the code snippet as answer and accept the same. It will be helpful for future users.